# In which countries are speed limit signs only valid until the next junction

Tags: legal, driving

In some countries (for example the United Kingdom) speed limit signs are valid until they are either superseded by another speed limit sign or some kind of speed limit end sign. Let's call these countries Type A.

In some other countries (for example Hungary) speed limit signs are also cancelled at any kind of junction. The logic here would be that cars coming from the other directions in the junction would not know what speed limit is in force on the road they are turning on (even if it's straight). Let's call these countries Type B.

Here are some examples how speed limits would be signposted in a Type A country:

[image: Type A]

Here are how the same road conditions would be signposted in a Type B country:

[image: Type B]

(red means the part of the road where the lower limit is enforced assuming the national/regional speed limit is higher than 60 units at that place)

While both approaches have their own advantages and disadvantages, obviously driving with the wrong mindset can mean you will either drive too slow, or more dangerously: too fast (as happened to me a few times, as I got my driving licence from a Type B country).

From my travels it seemed that Type A is much more prevalent, and actually I couldn't yet find a single other country than Hungary where Type B is the law. I tried to check some sites that contain notes on driving abroad (for example [Europa.EU](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/road_safety/going_abroad/index_en.htm)), but none of them seem to mention whether junctions act as speed limit derestrictions or not.

My question is which are the countries in Europe using Type B like laws?

Comment: depends not just on the country but also on the type of road. E.g. in the Netherlands speed limits are generally valid until changed, BUT on the highways they're valid until either changed OR until the next on-ramp. AND speed limits are considered implicit in many cases, e.g. there are no speed limit signs on entering most towns and cities, but the speed limit does change.

Comment: Regarding "cars coming from the other directions in the junction would not know what speed limit is in force on the road they are turning on", that's not the case in the UK. Any junction should have a single speed limit whichever direction you get there from, and there should be speed limit signs as you reach and leave the junction in the directions where the limit is different.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure the types A and B are as distinct as you believe.

Comment: @djr the speed limit signs in the UK are usually put on the side roads and not on the main one, so while the junction in fact does have one single speed limit, the place where that speed limit is defined is different in A and B jurisdictions, as shown on the image

Comment: @jwenting Implicit speed limits are a different things, but they are usually more well defined when you cross the border and see what the implicit limits are. When the implicit speed limit starts instead of the explicit one around junctions is the question here. Thanks for the note on the Netherlands

Comment: @SztupY BUT those signs are only placed (and only needed) if the speed limit on the side road is different from that on the through road it crosses. So signage is only needed when the speed limit changes, not to indicate it stays the same (as you seem to imply for Hungary).

Comment: I never got a driver's license but I have learned some of the theory, and as I remember it Denmark uses type B (I believe we were taught that *any* traffic sign was cancelled at a junction).

Comment: @SztupY Yes, the main road usually keeps its speed limit, but the point is that there should be signs for traffic going from the minor road to the main road and vice versa telling them the new limit that they are entering.

Comment: @djr yes, but where you put the signs is different in the two cases, and their meaning is slightly different as well

Comment: @jwenting in Hungary you have to signal if the speed limit remains the same, otherwise the junction will cancel their effect. Let me know if this is not obvious from the images

Comment: Type B sounds like a conspiracy by sign makers to assure they sell more speed limit signs ;-)

Comment: How is this not too broad?

Comment: Also, why not simply use Waze which always shows you the current speed limit?

Comment: @JonathanReez I'd prefer knowing the law than to rely on an app

Comment: "In which countries are speed limit signs only valid until the next junction?" is indeed too broad. Just check out the answer you got so far: you'll end up with an endless list of answers, mostly 1 per country. Make it 100% clear you want a **list**.

Comment: Slovenia also uses type B.

Answer (score 2):

Russia is Type B:

```
Зона действия знаков распространяется от места установки знака до 
ближайшего перекрестка за ним, а в населенных пунктах при отсутствии 
перекрестка — до конца населенного пункта
```

https://www.gazu.ru/znaki/3/3.24/

EDIT: Come to think of it. How would cars entering from intersection know the speed limit if it's not indicated? You will need a speed sign on every intersection anyway, otherwise you will have cars with different idea about speed limit on the same road, which is problematic.

Comment: Austria and Germany is Type A as far as I know

Comment: Many jurisdictions have a default speed limit for major highways, and a sign would be needed only to override the default.

Comment: "How would cars entering from intersection know the speed limit if it's not indicated?" They would know, because they passed a speed limit sign somewhere on their way. (otherwise the default implicit limit is in effect) This is actually much simpler than type B.

Comment: @DavidBalažic one missing sign and a wide area of road network becomes dual speed limit with confused drivers.